# How to access operations for a particular role from database in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, roles, rbac

I am trying to develop a real-time enterprise application which has rich Role Based Access Control features so i chosen Yii, which is rich in RBAC Support.

I have a use case where operations(Features) may differ with each users. A particular user may be allowed/requested to use particular feature/operations in the application. Eg: Administration Permissions and Users in [prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/en/features).

in prestashop, You can create as many users as needed with specific permissions set for each user. Perhaps you want to only allow a user to edit products or view order statistics, PrestaShop allows you to set specific settings for each user. This feature creates a secure store while giving access to those who need it.

[image: Screen Shot of prestashop Administration Permission and Users]

I want to implement the same as in the screenshot attached through Yii.

Is it possible to acheive through Yii RBAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with some differencies. I can write your own extension. But also you can use already written extension like [Yii-Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/). You can a little modify this ext for your goals.